# android -universal image loader does not load from cache

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader version 1.5.9 , this is my code, I want to cache the images to not download every time I reload the activity , I don't close the application but it downloads the image every time :

```
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
config= new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
                .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2) // default
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
                .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cacheDir)) // default
                .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
                .diskCacheFileCount(100)
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
                .build();
        imageLoader.init(config);

    imageLoader.displayImage(img, viewHolder.img);
```

What is the problem ? why does it download the image every time ?

Comment: Are you loading the image from a url?

Comment: Why don't you use glide on the place of universal image loader , see this link : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari yes , i'm loading it from a url

Comment: Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) then. It does image caching efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide, as it is the fastest way to access image
launched in android 5 
find the example codes below:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Don't suggest other libraries just because you don't know the library in question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation. Point 1 in [Useful Info](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info) clearly states that caching is **NOT** enabled by default. You need to set caching enabled in your config for it to actually cache anything.

```
       .cacheInMemory(true)
       .cacheOnDisk(true)
```